# Magento Styling Products in a Particular Category

Tags: css, magento

In Magento, how would I be able to treat products in a particular category differently?

Lets say, I have one category "Specials" and I want to have a bit different presentation of its products from the rest of the catalog products.

I initially thought about hooking custom styles up to the category class name that gets attached to BODY element. That, however, does not seem to be fool-proof, since if you directly access those products, they dont always show up as in that category (assuming cookies or sessions have a say in this) and custom styling is ignored.

Also though about assigning custom layout template to that category, but I am using those as layouts and not styles and I dont want to mix up the uses to avoid issues in the future.

Anyone had this concern before? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 code oriented solutions :

- If the notion of "category" is the fact that you're accessing a product through a category (on your product page, the breadcrumb display the category), you'll be able to cehck (somewhere in your catalog/product/view.phtml) the `Mage::registry('current_category')` which contains your current_category and compare it with your "particular category" (which could be stored as a configration variable)
- Otherwise, if you want your style applied even when you're not accessing your product via the category navigation, you'll have to manually check your product categories (`$product->getCategoryIds()`) and compare it with your "particular category" (which could be stored as a configration variable)

ps: keep in mind that a product can be assigned to multiple categories

Hops this helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you have particular category like special so Create new theme for Only Special category and assign that theme to special category from backend, you can easily assign different theme to different category from category management page in admin.

Or you can aslo assign different theme to products also from manage products page.

Comment: This is an option and a quite good one in terms of fallback too, but I think that up-keeping multiple stylesheets will be a burden. If you also have custom JS, then you would not wont to duplicate those into a new theme.